# Does compiling an empty file follow the C++ standard?

Tags: c++

There was an entry in the [1994 Obfuscated C contest](http://www.ioccc.org/1994/smr.hint) that qualified as the smallest quine.  It was just an empty file.

Is there something in the C++ spec that allows for compiling empty files?  If not, what is the bare minimum for a "valid program?"  I vaguely remember reading somewhere that there was a special case where an empty file is given a default implementation in the C++ spec, but I cannot find the reference.

I tried this, though I don't know that it is necessarily convincing.

```
$ rm main_empty.cpp
rm: cannot remove `main_empty.cpp': No such file or directory
$ touch main_empty.cpp
$ g++ -o empty main_empty.cpp
/usr/lib/gcc/.../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

With a little coddling, you can get around the missing main.

```
$ g++ -Wl,--defsym=_start=_exit -Wl,--undefined=_exit \
    -nostartfiles -static -o empty main_empty.cpp
```

UPDATE:

It was noted that the `main_empty.cpp` was redundant.  If you remove it from the command it compiles the same.

I added some static junk to the `main_empty.cpp` to see if it manifested in different behavior and it did not.  It did change the executable size however.

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo {
    Foo() {
        std::cout << "hi" << std::endl;
    }
} foo;
```

If you add a `main` to the file, and compile as normal it will output as you'd expect with typical static loading.

Comment: Until C++11, I believe all it needs is a newline. The `main` issue is nothing to do with compiling it.

Comment: `main_empty.cpp` in your last line is totally redundant.

Comment: When you have a look at the toolchain that generates the executable you've linked to, you'll notice that `cp smr.c smr` and `chmod +x smr` are applied instead of an actual C compiler.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

C++ draft from 2012-11-02.   3.6.1:

> A program shall contain a global function called main, which is the designated start of the program. It
>   is implementation-defined whether a program in a freestanding environment is required to define a main
>   function. [ Note: In a freestanding environment, start-up and termination is implementation-defined; start-
>   up contains the execution of constructors for objects of namespace scope with static storage duration;
>   termination contains the execution of destructors for objects with static storage duration. — end note ]

Comment: It's kind of interesting how no compiler will fail to compile that, it will just fail to link. It gets you halfway there.

Comment: @chris it says _program_ not _translation unit_. The linker is part of the process that generates a well-formed program.